# Hot string sends character by character after pressing any key, only in Notepad of Windows

Tags: autohotkey

I am facing a strange behavior in ahk hotstring, Only in Windows Notepad, not in other applications. When I type, a hotstring, instead of sending the whole word, it sends character by character after pressing some keys. For example, the following hotstring.

:*:.so::Stackoverflow{Space}

Actually it should type the word 'Stackoverflow ', when I type '.so' without quotes. But it sends 1 character, then it sends the another character only after I press any key (shift, contrl, alt, or a,b,c...). so for Stackoverflow, it expects me to press any key 12 times.

Please note that, this does not happen in other applications, like chrome, np++, word, pp etc. I could not understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual behaviour of the `Send` function, the fact that you haven't noticed is due to implementation of the text editor among others (such as buffer size or speed).

The `Send` function simulates a user pressing that sequence of keys. This is also dependent of the delay set with the `SetKeyDelay` function, which is 10 miliseconds by default.
Notepad++ probably processes the buffer before actually sending the keystrokes, as Windows' Notepad is pretty basic in its features. The same can be said for other software such as OneNote (but for large equations, you will also notice this behaviour).

I have a workaround for this:

- **Small size raw text**
  You are probably better off using `SendControl`, but I haven't tested so myself. You may also use `SetKeyDelay 0` but I am not aware of the behaviour of this.
- **Big size raw text**
  Instead of using the `Send` function for raw text, I wrote a function that would simply cache the data stored in the clipboard in a certain moment by using `ClipboardAll()`, empty the clipboard (using the built-in `A_Clipboard` variable), write the raw text I want to send into the clipboard, send `<Ctrl> + <V>` to paste it and then restore the previous contents of the clipboard.
  This makes it so much faster as you don't have to simulate keystrokes, but rather simply paste some contents from the clipboard.

Comment: I think, you have not understood my question well. SetKeyDelay is not useful in this case. However, the Clipboard copy paste is certainly useful in this situation.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: In AHK forums, they say it is a known issue in Notepad W11

Comment: Oh, yeah, I didn't read your question properly, as I thought you were seeing delayed sent keystrokes (as this has happened to me when I am sending keystorkes to OneNote in the case of writing large equations). I'll look into this issue when I have the time, but I am glad to hear that this workaround is useful for the time being.